# Is there a way to retrieve the ID of a newly created document in MongoDB for Appsmith?

Tags: appsmith

I'm using **Appsmith** and was wondering how I could **retrieve** the **ID of a newly created or updated document** when using the **MongoDB Connector**. I only receive this as response (when a new element is created):

```
{
  "n": 1
}
```

Do you know if this is some restriction of Appsmith? And are there possible workarounds? I also tried using normal JS, but it seems like Appsmith does not support Node.

Or can the query be extended? This is my query right now:

[ImageOfTheMongoDBInsert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aTd7.png)

Many thanks in advance!

Max

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, appsmith does not provide this in a simple or native way however you can perform this query through JS code within the same query, here one example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObUcz.png)